# Angular2- Enable Print Functionality in the same window on click of a PRINT link

Tags: typescript, angular2-template

In my angular app, I have a component where in the template I have a print link on click of which i have to enable print functionality.I am trying something like this in my HTML-

```
<div>
<a href="#" (click)="print()">PRINT</a>
</div>
```

and in .ts file-

```
print(): void {
    let printContents, popupWin;
    printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;
    popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write(`
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>Print tab</title>
          <style>
          //........Customized style.......
          </style>
        </head>
    <body onload="window.print();window.close()">${printContents}</body>
      </html>`
    );
    popupWin.document.close();
}
```

This works but it opens a new window for print. Is there anyw ay , I can have that in same window.
I also tried-

```
<a href="javascript:window.print();">Print</a>
```

But both of the above approach does not work. Any idea how can i get my page printed in angular2.

Comment: `href="javascript:window.print();"` does not work in what particular way?

Comment: @torazaburo the styles are totally distorted.The page looks distorted.

Comment: You will probably need to define some `@media print` styles to make the printed page come out the way you want.

Comment: writing CSS inside STYLE tag works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works fine. We will be able to print the particular component However we need to add the styles inside  tag in document.write function.

Answer (score 0):

use onclick to call print().

Try this `<a href="#" onclick="print();">Print</a>`

Comment: Why will this work better/differently than `href="javascript:window.print()"`?